# Reverse Engineering Sequence Diagrams from Java Code in Rational Software Architect

Tags: java, rational-rsa

I've installed RSA 9.0.  I have followed the instructions for reverse engineering, but after dragging and dropping my Java classes onto the sequence diagram, the method calls aren't generated automatically.  I also tried the Java to UML feature, but that only seems to generate class diagrams.  Is this feature even supported?

Comment: so you have searched in IBM Developer works? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/08/0610_xu-wood/

Comment: @Hector, Yes if you look at the bottom the instructions for the sequence diagram, they don't really tell you that the method calls will be generated automatically.

Comment: doesnt this part explain how to get "The following example demonstrates how to identify an entire inheritance tree with optional attributes and operations:"?